# Can the notifications of new activity on the main page be turned off?

Tags: support

When there's new activity on the site, I'm notified about it by the system on the main page. It wasn't there before and I liked it better. Can I turn it off somehow? It startles me and I don't see how I could benefit from it.

[image]

Comment: which notification do you mean? (Preferably can you grab a screen shot and highlight what you mean?)

Comment: @WillieWong I've added a screenshot.

Comment: huh, I've never seen that before. Sorry, don't think I can help. Maybe someone from the Stack team will drop by.

Comment: @Willie: It's brand new; started yesterday (3/8/12) I think. Keep the browser on the page but don't refresh, and it will be pop up.

Comment: @ymar: +1. I too find it a bit annoying.

Comment: @Arturo: I see now. Thanks. I don't generally leave the main page open in a tab that is on top, so I didn't notice it at all!

Comment: It's just awful. I second the motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to disable it at the moment and none planned that I know of.

I realize it's not an ideal solution, but in the meantime you can ignore it and refresh the page at your convenience as you would before.

Comment: As a programmer, do you think there's a possibility of a javascript hack around to make the browser ignore the incoming (I assume) AJAX updates about the new activity? (I'm thinking of a script a la greasemonkey which will override the function which displays the new activity.)

Comment: @J.D. I unfortunately have no idea. I haven't done much web development at all.

Comment: @J.D. - if you're using Firefox, you can just disable websocket support.

Comment: @Shog9: Will this affect anything besides the notifications?

Comment: @TheChaz chat also uses websockets, but should fall back to polling if they're unavailable. Most sites should do something similar.